# fire two events simultaneously in jquery on same selector

Tags: jquery, simultaneous

This should be easy, but I'm a newbie...

How can I make the show function and the click to animate function work as one?

```
function scrollit() {
    $("#scrollDown").show();
    $("#scrollDown").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#scrollDown').offset().top}, 1500);
    });
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/elasticGurl/3r6Jp/4/

What's supposed to happen is

1. the button is clicked
2. the hidden div scrollDown is displayed
3. At the same time as #2, it should also move down a bit at the same time

The problem is it needs to be clicked twice in order for it to move down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your click function is on your hidden div instead of on your button

```
function scrollit() {

    $("#scrollDown").show();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#scrollDown').offset().top}, {duration:1500, queue:false});
}​
```

Comment: p.s. I'd drop the scrollit function and just put the click binding onto the button

Comment: Ok, i changed it (same js fiddle URL) but I still have to click it twice for it to move. You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/elasticGurl/23wKx/4/embedded/result/

Comment: how do I put the click binding onto the button?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/23wKx/5/ I added a extra property onto the onto the animation to allow it to execute at the same time as the show

Comment: The $("#button").click(...) will bind the click event, that will need to happen inside the $(document).ready(function() { /*binding here*/});

Comment: p.s.s. mark mine as the correct answer because it does show and scroll at the same time :P

Answer (score 2):

You are just binding the event of click you need to fire the event too:

```
function toggleDiv() {

$("#scrollDown").show().click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#scrollDown').offset().top}, 1500);
});
   $("#scrollDown").click();
}
```

Comment: fantastic. Thank you!  But how do I remove the delay from the action? If you notice, it waits for a bit before it moves the div down.  New with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/elasticGurl/23wKx/2/

Comment: i suggest you to remove the click event and just fire the animate and it will toggle everytime when the clicked on red thing:

function toggleDiv() {

$("#scrollDown").show();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#scrollDown').offset().top}, 800);
  
}

Answer (score 0):

try with **jQuery 1.8.2**

```
$(document).on('click','p#scrolltest', function (){
  $("div#scrollDown").show('fast', function(){
       $('body').animate({
           scrollTop: $('#scrollDown').offset().top
           }, 1500);
        });
});
```

[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/3r6Jp/15/)

Comment: Thanks for this, but I actually need it to scroll down instead of just show the div. At least that's what it does for me. It's going to be on a mobile device, so when they click the button, the page scrolls up a bit to show the form. Does that make sense?

Comment: isn't it scroll down now in one click? Check plz

Comment: On my screen (your jfiddle) , it just shows the form, but doesn't make it move up.

Comment: I tried putting coordinates like this:  .offset({ top: 0, left: 0 })   but it just overlaps the button

Comment: Please check my HTML markup too. I have updated CSS too.check now

Comment: interesting. It doesn't move in Firefox, but it works in Chrome and Safari. Any ideas how to fix it in FF?

Comment: its working on my `firefox V16` with `jQuery 1.8.3.min.js`. do not check in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/FSfRR/1/

```
   var count = 0;
   $(".checkout_btn").click(function() {
       $("#scrollDown").show();
      count++;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#scrollDown').offset().top}, 1500);
      if(count==1)
          $(this).trigger('click');
      else 
          count = 0;
   });
```

Comment: instead of count you can use `.one()`

Comment: Disagree, here is a recursive call

Comment: This works in chrome, safari and ff! Thank you!   How do I use one(); I tried it but it stopped working. I'd be curious to know the syntax. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Your answer works, but the one below (Koenyn) is shorter. Thanks anyway!! :)